# CSS: How do I set <link media="" /> as inline CSS with @media if the media type is a phrase?

Tags: iphone, css, mobile

How do you set  as inline if it's not one of the words listed on the single word media types? (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types)

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width:480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The handheld media type is ignored by the iPhone, but I'd imagine the external call above would be in a format somewhat like this:

```
@media handheld
  {
  body {margin:0; padding:0;}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example V at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

> @media screen and (color), projection
>   and (color) { ... }